# Horizontal alignment of elements inside a lockup element in stackTemplate of TVML

Tags: tvos, apple-tv, tvml, tvjs

I need to have an image and a text beside it in a lockup element. 
Text should not appear as an overlay on the image. It should appear next to the image. Any help would be highly appreciated.

(This is part of a higher requirement where I need to update a typical lockup element to this custom lockup element on highlight. Any help on how to achieve this would be highly highly appreciated )

Answer (score 0):

Part 1 would work with `buttonLockup`, I guess. Use `row` to arrange "side by side":

```
<buttonLockup>
  <row>
    <badge ...>
    <text ...>
  </row>
</buttonLockup>
```

(https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/ATV_Template_Guide/LockupElements.html)

Comment: `row` can't be a subelement of `buttonLockup`, and `buttonLockup` can't be a subelement of  `section`

Comment: I need to expand(width wise) a `lockup` element and show a description on focus in `section` inside a `shelf` of `stackTemplate`. Bring it back to normalcy once it goes out of focus.

Comment: Well, Apple's docs clearly state that `row` CAN be a subelement of `buttonLockup`... it won't work with `lockup`, that's true.

Comment: No. `row` can contain but can't be a subelement of `buttonLockup`.